# Use document.getElementById when DOM has not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code in a project and I want to remove jQuery library from the project. So I am trying to convert this in to full javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#price-button").click(priceButtonClicked), 
    getURLParameter("run") && $("#price-button").click()
});

var priceCell = $("#priceCell");
```

I tried this using `document.getElementById` but the issue is my page has not rendered and therefore the elements are not in present at that stage. I have no idea how to overcome this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put your logic inside a window load event handler.  Or include your script immediately before the `</body>` so the elements exist at the point the script runs.

Comment: Either A) Use a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (either relying on native support, or using a bundler like WebPack or Rollup), or B) Use `defer` on your `script` tag, or C) Put your `script` tag at the end of the document, just prior to the `</body>` tag. (In roughly that order of preference.)